# Check if a comma separated list contains a specific number

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a column that is a text string that contains a comma separated list of ids. It could look something like this:

> 1,2,3,45,65,23245,564747,23,121,54,65,345678

I need to find if it contains a specific id or not. To get if it just contains a number would be fairly straightforward to do with a regular expression, but the problem is that for example the id 4 is not in the list but of lot of the ids contains a 4. Maybe it's still possible to write a regular expression that can handle that, but that's above my level. Or is there another way to solve this in SQL?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I don't actually have a column containing a comma separated list. What I have is a listagg that is made from several rows from a query, and I want to be able to apply a filter to it. I just tried to simplify the question so it would be more focused on the actual problem. I didn't realize that doing this would result in more answers on the database design than on the actual question.

Comment: If you have comma-separated lists in your SQL database, you have an error in your database design (i.e. you are missing a table). Fix the error, not the query.

Comment: This has been asked here at least 100 times, I just linked to one such thread. The accepted answer there is also the accepted answer in half the threads at least. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing values in a comma separated list is a very bad design pattern, it gives nothing but headaches. If you can, normalize it.

If you can't, you can search for a specific ID using the commas in the comparison:

```
WHERE [Column] LIKE '%,4,%'
   OR [Column] LIKE '4,%'
   OR [Column] LIKE '%,4'
```

Comment: ... or you simply do

WHERE ',' || [Column] || ',' LIKE '%,4,%'

Answer (score 6):

As others said, comma separated values are bad, but if you want anyway, this is one way:

```
select * from t where REGEXP_LIKE (col , '(^|,)4(,|$)')
```